# Control display of HINT.css library tooltip with jQuery events

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide, mouseleave

I am using [`HINT.css`](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/) and would like to have the tip hide when the div/class is clicked and turned on when the use mouses out of the div/class. I thought what I have here was pretty straight forward. I am surprised it didn't work, what am I missing?

```
<div class="promo">
   <div class="offer hint--top hint--info hint--rounded hint--info" 
    data-hint="PUT SOME COOL COPY, TO GET PEOPLE TO CLICK!!!"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $( '.promo' ).on('click','.offer', function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
   $( '.promo' ).on('mouseleave','.offer', function(){
   $(this).show();
});
}); //end of document ready
```

Comment: which part isn't working? does it give you any javascript errors? check your console and post the results.

Comment: have you included jquery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is created by the way in which the [`HINT.css`](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/) library is working. The tooltips are pseudo-elements, so although the jQuery click event added will hide the element, it will immediately appear again due to the HINT.css code `:hover` class which is still applying to the element.

But we can workaround this and add in the functionality by adding a `display:none` rule to the pseudo-element as a class which is added or removed by jQuery.

For example:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('.promo').on('click','.offer', function() {
    $(this).addClass('fakeHide');
  });

  $('.promo').on('mouseleave','.offer', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('fakeHide');
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.fakeHide[data-hint]:before, .fakeHide[data-hint]:after {
  display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="promo"><span class="offer hint--bottom hint--rounded hint--info" data-hint="PUT SOME COOL COPY!!">I am a promotion - hover over me</span></div>
```

This was a difficult one to demo. For some reason both jsFiddle and jsBin do not show the tooltips in *edit* mode, however they do work in *live preview* mode.

[**See demo**](http://jsbin.com/ezuhad/2) or [**edit demo**](http://jsbin.com/ezuhad/2/edit) - and remember it only appears in live preview mode!

Comment: Thanks so much! I am going to do some reading on pseudo-elements!

Comment: Happy to help. It was a good question :-) As for pseudo-elements, my advice is "don't go looking for them in the DOM" - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5041526/637889

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you click on div it hide the div but same time it firing `mouseleave` on div where you again calling show. that why it never will be hidden.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tf8Wc/)

Comment: `+1` for explaining what the problem is

Comment: Thanks! The JSFIDDLE is blank, I appreciate your help though.

Comment: @antonio Sorry, but I changed url, check again

Comment: Great, thanks! 
So i commented out the alert, and fired some additional clicks and the tooltip continues to fire.

Eventually clicking in the div/class will fire a slider, which is why I want the tooltip to stop. I figure the user has been alerted by the tooltip which is why I'd like it to cease.

Answer (score 0):

The Code which you have mentioned above does exactly what you want..

[http://jsfiddle.net/MjFRe/][1]

[1]: JsFiddle Demo

Comment: This demo shows nothing and should really be a comment on the question.